# HTML Not getting image in an Express.js Web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

I'm trying to use a image in my HTML file, but the image won't appear and I assume I got the path right, or something wrong with express.

**I am using an Express.JS app with E.js**

Could anybody point out where I'm going wrong? The image simply isn't found by the browser for some reason or another

The header is a partial and I'm trying to have the image appear everywhere but I can't seem to get the path right.

`header.ejs`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>


<header>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="assets/scriptLogo.png" class="logo">
        <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/mission">Our Mission/Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="/outing">Golf outing</a></li>
                <li><a href="/petition">SI Ferry petition</a></li>
                <li><a href="/blooddrive">Blood Drive</a></li>
                <li><a href="/news">In the news</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sponsors">Our sponsors</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="pageheading">
            <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:#b12121;background-color:gray">
            <h1>
                John G. Chipura Foundation
            </h1>
            <p1>
                The on-going legacy of a good American.
            </p1>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</html>
```

File Structure:

[image: File Structure]

Can anybody point how how to access an image from the `assets` folder in the `header.ejs` file?
Do I need to do something in my express main file?

Comment: The path is going to be based on the URL of the HTML document and the URL of the image. A screenshot of your filesystem doesn't tell us what either of those are.

Comment: @Quentin So what should I show you then?

Comment: There is no specific URL of the header file since it is a partial. I can give you the URL of every page it is gonna be used, but that's like 10 pages

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I just moved the assets into the pages folder where express is set static.